# CSS Position an Icon Image at the End of Text in a Class

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

A site I am working on uses a small image icon of an upward-right pointing arrow on off-site links as a designation to the user that "this link goes away from this site".  Currently the image-icon is on the left-side (beginning) of the link text.  What we would like to do is move it to the end of the text.  This is proving difficult.  I am able to move the icon to the far right of the class container the link text is in, but not to the end of the text.  At the far right of the container does not look so great.

The css comes from an outside contractor and we are now maintaining it and making edits/changes.  I'm okay with css, but this is beyond my meeger chops.

Example:
As it is now:

```
->foo
->foobarbizbaam
```

What I would like:

```
foo->
foobarbizbaam->
```

Not looking so well:

```
foo           ->
foobarbizbaam ->
```

Code snippets from our app.css file:

```
a.external, a.external-link {
   background-image: url(/assets/img/external-link.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 0.6875rem; 
}

.sidebar > ul > li a {
   background-color: #fff; 
}

/* this one positions the icon                        */
/* currently this puts icon at left-side of link text */
.sidebar > ul > li a.external {
   background-position: 0.5rem 0.7rem; 
}

.sidebar > ul > li > a {
   padding-left: 0.9375rem;
   padding-right: 0.9375rem;
   border-top: 1px solid #666;
   border-left: 1px solid #666;
   border-right: 1px solid #666; 
}
```

Any way this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: So the 2nd or the 3rd example is the desired result?

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: you can use it as pseudo element `:after{..}`

Comment: 2nd example is desired.  Cannot really show the html. Our code base is so extremely complex. We user Foundation, PHP, and a home-grown xml structure for displaying everything.  How to use :after{...} in this css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the CSS `::after` ([::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)) selector to add the image directly after the links.

Assuming that the HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="external" target="_blank">Stackoverflow</a>
```

You should be able to accomplish what you want by using the following CSS:

```
a.external:after {
  content: url('http://placehold.it/16x16'); /* Replace with your image icon path although, preferably, you should use an icon font instead. */
  margin-left: 5px; /* Adjust margin as needed */
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sbeliv01/zrkg6rbb/1/

Comment: This is awesome.  It works perfectly.  Just need to resize icon image now, but that is in my abilities.  Thank you so much.  Thank you to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with html you can add the image behind the text in the html, instead of a background in the css. 
Something like:

```
<span>text here <img src="img.jpg"></span>
```

This should put the image right after the text

Comment: Thanks, but that would be too easy. ;)   the way our code base is structured, this is not do-able.

Comment: @JohnCowan Yeah that was the easy answer. Try using the `:after` psuedo selector then, that would be the best way of going about it. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp